# Magento + Zend OpCache

Tags: php, cache, performance

Has anyone any experience on configuring Magento + Zend OpCache on Apache ?

I have configured in my testing environment using Nginx + PHP-FPM and Zend OpCode with PHP 5.5.9 and it seems to work fine but i don't know if is ready for production since it is still beta.

My other question is, i have multiple Magento installation in the same server, may this be a problem since their files are the same (but may have different code) ?

Any other recommendation on it's configuration to have e faster Magento site?

Answer (score 2):

> My other question is, i have multiple Magento installation in the same server, may this be a problem since their files are the same (but may have different code) ?

We had the problem in the past (with APC), that with two instances configured the same way in local.xml that they wrote in the other apc cache (live and stage) which was really bad and both instances showed a weird behaviour.

I guess the same can happen with Zend OpCache.

Comment: Actually in APC i think you can set some PREFIX in local.xml and layouts are saved as PREFIX_name but with Zend OpCache i am not sure. Normally it should work fine because there could be a lot of files with the same name but with different code.

Comment: The question is, what is the "name" based on? path + filename - everything is fine. htdocspath + filename? ERROR. Don't know :)

Comment: I think it should be path + filename: http://prntscr.com/384qn8

Comment: If you are using symlink based deployments pay special attention to this document: http://codinghobo.com/opcache-and-symlink-based-deployments/